# How to configure SMTPS (port 465) in postfix?

Tags: postfix

I enabled port 465, by uncommenting these lines in master.cf:

```
smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
```

And port 465 was enabled. But, when I used PHPMailer to connect to it using SSL, it says it couldn't connect. But when I use STARTTLS, it works. Why is that? I think it is meant to work when we use SSL to connect to it. Any solutions please?

The PHPMailer conf:

```
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host       = 'example.com';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;
    $mail->Port       = 465;
    $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
```

main.cf:

```
# TLS configuration starts here

tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom

# SMTP from your server to others
smtp_tls_key_file = /some/place/to/ssl/domain.key
smtp_tls_cert_file = /some/place/to/ssl/domain.crt
smtp_tls_CAfile = /some/place/to/ssl/domain.crt
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
smtp_tls_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
smtp_tls_loglevel = 0
smtp_tls_session_cache_database =
    btree:/var/lib/postfix/smtp_tls_session_cache

# SMTP from other servers to yours
smtpd_tls_key_file = /some/place/to/ssl/domain.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /some/place/to/ssl/domain.crt
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /some/place/to/ssl/domain.crt
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 0
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database =
    btree:/var/lib/postfix/smtpd_tls_session_cache

# TLS configuration ends here
```

Comment: Show the mail log.

Comment: `smtpd_tls_cert_file` and `smtpd_tls_CAfile` are the same? Seems more likely a phpmailer issue.  Set `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'` and `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2`